# QGraphicsView not repainting on scroll event

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

QT 4.7

I have a QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene. The scene has a custom QGraphicsItem the whole scene is not displayed at one time, so it has a viewport.

I'm overriding the paint() method of my QGraphicsItem as follows:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter,
           const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
           QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setClipRect(option->exposedRect);
    painter->save();

    // Default identity matrix
    QTransform transform;

    // Apply some transform later

    // The next line breaks stuff
    painter->setTransform(transform);

    // m_image is just a preloaded pixmap (i.e. watermark on all of these items).
    painter->drawImage(QPoint(0,0), this->m_image);
    painter->restore();

    // Snip, do more drawing...
}
```

If I ever try to setTransform on the QPainter (i.e. if I'm trying to rotate the item), the view stops repainting the scene as a response to the horizontal or vertical scrollbars used to pan. The view also stops resizing the scene when I zoom in or zoom out.

The view will refresh if I resize the window or drag the window offscreen and then back onscreen. I've been looking over the [QPainter Documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qpainter.html) as well as the examples and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm assuming it's something to do with the coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess:

The `QPainter` that comes to your `paint` method already has a transform on it that takes into account the viewport attributes (scale, rotation, etc.). When you call `setTransform` within your paint method you are blowing all that away. You probably want to perform a matrix operation on the existing transform rather than creating a new one.

Since you are calling `setClipRect` on your painter but then trying to paint under a completely different transform, you are painting outside your clip rect and nothing is happening.

It works when you resize or drag the window off screen because that forces a "redraw everything," so your clip rect includes your painting area in your alternate transform. Although I'm surprised it would appear in the correct location.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. `painter->setTransform(transform, true);` fixed the problem.